# HTMX hx-delete with hx-include together

Tags: python, flask, htmx

I am using the `hx-delete` to delete a record from db table. but along with it, I need to send other parameters with the request using `hx-include`.

```
   hx-trigger="click" 
   hx-delete="{{ url_for('htmx_delete', task_id=task.id) }}" 
   hx-include="[name='ordertype'],[name='orderby'],[name='filterby'],[name='searchField']" 
   hx-target="#tasks-list" 
   hx-swap="innerHTML" 
   hx-confirm="Are you sure you wish to delete this task?"
```

On the server side (Flask), I am using the **DELETE** method as well:

```
@app.route('/htmx_delete/<task_id>', methods=['GET', 'DELETE'])
def htmx_delete(task_id):
```

I can see the additional parameters in the payload. However, As expected I can't retrieve the additional parameters using fLASK `request.args.get`or `request.form.get`.

How can I access the additional parameters using the DELETE HTTP verb? I can make this work using the GET verb on the client and server side, but I want to stick with DELETE.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can retrieve the payload:

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs
payload_dict = parse_qs(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
```